# How to call and convert an int/NSNumber when calling on a sqlite3 database in Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, database, sqlite, nsnumber

Thanks in advance for taking your time out for reading and hoping to assist me. I am relatively new to coding and the current problem I am facing is;

I have built a sqlite3 database, with three columns which are respectively stored as; string, float and an int. When trying to read and represent the columns, I am having trouble in finding a method in order to represent the float and int values.

The three properties which are stores in the database are set as;

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonaomtic, strong) NSNumber *price;
@property (nonaomtic, strong) NSNumber *quantity;
```

I'm not sure if maybe changing the latter two properties into float and int would make a difference?

However, the main confusion for me lies in the following code I have made in order to call on the data base;

```
-(void)readDataFromDatabase{
[self.stock removeAllObjects];

sqlite3 *database;

if (sqlite_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
   char *sqlStatement = "select * from entries";
   sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
   while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW{
      char *n = sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
      char *p = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 2);
      chat *q = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 3);

      NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:n];
      NSNumber *price = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:p];
      NSNumber *quantity = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:q];

      Data *data = [[Data alloc] initWithData:name thePrice: price theQuantity:quantity];
      [self.stock addObject:data];
    }
  }
  sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

My common sense tells me the problem lies in this section;

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:n];
NSNumber *price = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:p];
NSNumber *quantity = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:q];
```

I'm not sure how I should approach the NSNumber? I'm aware the NSString stringWithUTF8String is not correct, but I don't know the equivalent for NSNumber.

I would really appreciate any insight and help on this matter.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you think `NSString stringWithUTF8String` is correct? also, you are on the right track in replacing `NSNumber` with `float` and `int` if that's what they require, (eg. `@property (nonaomtic, strong) float price;`, etc. Since you are declaring them in your header you would only need to do: `price = (your float value);`...

Comment: Thank you for your response!

My understanding thus far seems to alert me that trying to set an NSNumber a method which is applicable to the class of NSString to just not be correct? As I believe (please correct me if I am wrong) that the purpose of stringWithUTF8String is called in order to allow the char (a c "object") to be read in a manner which corresponds with NSString (an objective-c object). And I believe, that ints and floats are a common "object" between the two languages, so no conversion has to be done in that manner?

I look forward to your response, thank you :)

Comment: Oh! that's what you mean... i wasn't paying attention and only saw the one you were setting for `name` which looks correct. The others, no, you wouldn't set like that. All they really need is the basic `C` style declarations. (eg. `float price = 10.2;`, or `int quantity = 5;`), but since you are declaring them in a header I assume all you'd need is `price = 10.2;`, `quantity = 5;`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Changing the properties into int and float has eliminated the error message, and I have changed the code as you have suggested, it now reads as;

`NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:n]; float *price = p;
 int *quantity = q;`

However, there are still error messages in the code regarding the `float *p = sqlite3_colum_int(compiledStatement, 2);`

It says "incompatible pointer types initialising 'float*' with an expression of type int".

The same goes for the following line of code `int *q = sqlite3_colum_int(compiledStatement, 3);`

Comment: Yeah, you don't need the `*` for the `float` or `int`, since that would signify they are pointers, which they are not. Also, you can use `NSInteger` instead of `int` in case the value could be large and/or the program will be used on 32/64-bit systems (it's safer).

Comment: BTW: I'd suggest moving to some kind of a SQL generator/wrapper.  There really is no need to write it yourself (in fact, your code is incorrect in how it handles errors).  FMDB, CoreData or Realms would likely make for simpler, more maintainable, code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with what you've mentioned for `float` and `int`. `Float` does not need to be referenced like `NSString` because it's size does not vary between 32-bit and 64-bit systems. If your integer is larger then I would recommened using `NSInteger` for that value:

```
char *n = sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
float p = sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2);
int q = sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3);

NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:n];
float price = p;
NSInteger quantity = q;
```

Note: You don't the `*` for the float or int values, since they are not pointers.

You might even be able just to do (If you are already declaring the properties in your header):

```
name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
price = sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2);
quantity = sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3);
```

To check the values you can use `NSLog`:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %.02f %li", name, price, quantity);
```

For completeness sake, if you wanted to make the `float` and `int` into `NSNumber`:

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:n];
NSNumber *price = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:p];
NSNumber *quantity = [NSNumber numberWithInt:q];
```

With the properties in your header declared:

```
name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:n];
value = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:p];
quantity = [NSNumber numberWithInt:q];

NSLog(@"%@ %@.02f %@", name, price, quantity);
```

There are multiple ways to get your result, and that's what makes Objective-C quite flexible.

Comment: Thank you so much! The error messages have been eliminated by removing the *. You have been very helpful, I really appreciate it. 

I now have another problem! Which lies with the custom class of UITableViewCell, as I have made a primary and secondary label object, however the secondary label is set to display the price but it does not take a float.

The code is quiet long and my breakdown of my problem will not fit in these comments! So I have to wait before the "only may post a question every 90 mins" is over. I would really appreciate your help on this case when it is posted :)

Comment: You're welcome! Since that's a different issue maybe mark this answer as "correct" if it solved the immediate issue in the scope of this question. Maybe try using the `NSNumber` method for your `UITableViewCell`, since it's native `Objective-C`... Getting values into the UI is slightly different depending on what you're doing, so I'd recommend posting another question with as much information about it as possible.